# vba to Autofilter using "<>" for criteria to filter on fontcolor

Tags: excel, vba

This is snippet of my code:

```
Dim col As Integer
col = InputBox("Please enter column number to search", "Need Input", 0)
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

With ActiveSheet
Set rnData = .UsedRange
    With rnData
        .AutoFilter Field:=col, Criteria1:="<>RGB(0, 0, 255)", Operator:=xlFilterFontColor      
    End With
End With
```

This throws an error but works when I remove  <> and "" to select blue font but I want non blue font. 
Questions:
 The col that I want to filter has some sentences in which few words have different font Colors(red,blue,green...) or all just black 
1) I want to filter on non blue color.
2) Filter on only black fontcolor with no words being of different color.how do I achieve that?
3) Is there a way to give the colummn as alphabets instead of column number- basically does the field accept alphabets instead of numbers to indicate column.

When i used @jeeped code for an eg[image]

after running the code then it gives this[image]

which is what I am not clear why it is not able  find non blue.

Comment: If you make `col a string` then use this `i = Range(col & 1).Column` then you can use `Field:=i,`

Comment: Thanks. It works for my 3rd question. Do u know the solution to the 1st and 2nd question.Is it possible?

Comment: Usually one would filter color that they want, not what they don't want. You may have to loop through the cells.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used a method of collecting all non-conforming (i.e. *non-blue*) values from the filter field into an array and then filtering on the array. Your problem seemed similar so I adapted the procedure for the filter field's font color.

```
Sub Not_Blue()
    Dim r As Long, iFLD  As Long
    Dim dNOTBLUs As Object    'New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Set dNOTBLUs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dNOTBLUs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    
        iFLD = 3   ' get your filter column here
        For r = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, iFLD).End(xlUp).Row
            '~~> collect unique non-blue values
            If .Cells(r, iFLD).Font.Color <> RGB(0, 0, 255) Then _
                dNOTBLUs.Add Key:=.Cells(r, iFLD).Text, Item:=.Cells(r, iFLD).Value2
        Next r
    
        .AutoFilter Field:=iFLD, Criteria1:=dNOTBLUs.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        
        'column iFLD is filtered for all non-blur fonts
        'do something with the filtered results here
        
    End With
    
    dNOTBLUs.RemoveAll: Set dNOTBLUs = Nothing
End Sub
```

That collects a unique list of all non-blue values into a scripting dictionary. It uses the unique **key** list as the array to filter on. Essentially, you are abandoning the `xlFilterFontColor` but achieving the same results.

[image: AutoFilter by not color]
                <sup>Before</sup>

[image: AutoFilter by not color results]
                <sup>After</sup>

---

<sub>If you can convert the late binding of the Scripting.Dictionary to early binding, you must add **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** to the VBE's Tools ► References.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting error at                                                            .AutoFilter Field:=iFLD, Criteria1:=dNOTBLUs.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues       Type mismatch error on this statement. Is it because I have sentences in it, where few words are blue and not all?

Comment: Well, I assure you that I do not photoshop sample images. Perhaps you could add some sample data and detail the error you are receiving. Off-hand, you might try changing the `.Cells(r, iFLD).Text` to `.Cells(r, iFLD).Value`.

Comment: It worked when I just had blue font used.I have shown the eg in my actual question where it did not completely work. An another issue that I am having is when I shift the titles to start from 3rd row leaving first two lines empty. I changed                  For r =4 but it throws an error saying "AutoFilter method of Range class failed". Is there something that I need to change for this code not to throw error.

Comment: please see @Jeeped the eg in my actual question where it failed. does the code not work for this. But this helped answer my 2nd question. Is there any change which will do the trick and also how do I change when the headers start from 3rd Row